# Optimising UITableview to process huge set of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using core data to store and retrieve datas that Im fetching from web services.
Im displaying those datas in a table view.
Following is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    StatutoryMappingCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KnowledgeMainCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }
    cell.statMapping.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

`self.items` contains the datas that has to be loaded in the `tableview`.

The problem that Im facing is,

1. Im getting huge set of data from the server which is like 2000 records. So the `tableview` loading is getting very slow. How can I optimise the above code to handle such huge record?
2. Is there any ways that I can do pagination in iOS where the user can click load more button at the bottom to retrieve  more contents as in facebook?

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527262/uitableview-with-magicalrecord-huge-data-set?rq=1

Comment: in here you need to go for lazy loading or prefetch loader method

Comment: Can you please provide some examples?

Comment: Use an `NSFetchedResultsController` rather than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MGR, Using NsfetchedresultsController you can achieve it.

Here you can query the data from CD.

For Swift :

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Here you can set the limit of Fetch Using FetchRequest property 

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

For Objective c:

create one property in .h file

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

in .m implement this

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When ever new data saved in coreData, it will automatically reflect in Tableview with the help of NFC delegate Metods.

```
// MARK: Fetched Results Controller Delegate Methods
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}
```

// This will be called after all changes happened in cell.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

// This will be called Every time whenever you delete or insert or moving the cell

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ToDoCell
            configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
        break;
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Thats it. Hope this will help you.

For reference follow this link.https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/10/optimizing-core-data-performance-using-nsfetchedresultscontrolle

Comment: Thank you...is there any objective c code for the same?

Comment: Yeah i will Edit you in a minute.